# php, normal date is correct, but gmdate is not accurate

Tags: php

I have to do calculates with GMT date, but it looks like there is a bug, or I dont understand something.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
// calculations will come
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
echo $time.'<br>';
```

this prints the same dates, as it was expected.
But this:

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>';
$time = strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
// calculations will come
$time = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
echo $time.'<br>';
```

is not the same. What am I doing wrong? I have to use GMT time, its an international site.

Comment: Same for me: http://codepad.org/VexVZd8a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) uses the local time zone, unless the passed string has timezone information. Dates of the format `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` do not contain time zone information.

In `strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`, the function `strtotime` assumes that the passed string specifies a date in the local timezone, but it actually is in GMT.

Comment: I don't know if it's `strtotime` fault. It's rather how gmdate works

Comment: It's not the fault of a single function. The fault comes from having incorrect expectations when calling a combination of functions.

Comment: Depending on your exact requirements, possible workaround are (1) not using gmdate, (2) including the time zone in the output format of gmdate and (3) not using strtotime.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with it, but I'll give a try.

My results are:

```
2014-07-22 10:21:11
2014-07-22 10:21:11
2014-07-22 08:21:11
2014-07-22 06:21:11
```

Look at your timezone in `php.ini`

I have in my `php.ini`:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```

What is GMT+2

`gmdate` tries to calculate GMT date, so for me (rather for my timezone GMT+2), it subtracts 2 hours. Then when using again `gmdate` from `strtotime` result, it simply does the same. Because I have set GMT+2, it subtracts again 2 hours because it wants to calculate GMT date.